# Troubleshooting: wireless SSH connections to Raspbian Stretch

Tags: pi-3, networking, ssh, raspbian-stretch

I'm having trouble with wireless SSH on a RPi 3 B+ running Raspbian Stretch.

I've enabled wifi via `raspi-config`

I've got an empty `ssh` file at the root directory.

I've got a `/wpa_supplicant.conf` file that lists my network info.

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
country=<my country code>

network={
    ssid=<my ssid>
    psk=<password>
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

I can ssh into the RPi when attached using an ethernet cable but it fails when I try to run do it wirelessly.  When I run `ssh pi@<wlan0 inet address>`, it times out.

Is there some other step that I need to perform in order to be able to ssh into the device wirelessly?

### Update with more info

Here's the output of `ip link show`, `ip addr show`, and `ip route show`

#### ip link show

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:29:84:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:7c:d1:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

#### ip addr show

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:29:84:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.2/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ad3:ab2d:41bd:7a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:7c:d1:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.11.21/24 brd 192.168.11.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::36c7:9602:db6:2c3a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

#### ip route show

```
default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.2.2 metric 202 
default via 192.168.11.1 dev wlan0 src 192.168.11.21 metric 303 
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.2 metric 202 
192.168.11.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.11.21 metric 303
```

Comment: Ok.... some basics. Can you add the output of these commands into your question? `ip link show` `ip addr show` `ip route show`.

Comment: on raspberry pi 3B+ **you must set the country code** - e.g. have `country=XX` (where XX depends on what part of the world you live in) in `wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: I've updated my post to include the output of those commands.

Comment: Also, I've added in my country code to the `wpa_supplicant.conf` (right under the `ctrl_interface` line).  I rebooted the Rpi but saw no change in behavior.

Comment: You wrote "*I've got an empty ssh file at the root directory*". There is no root directory or do you mean `/` which is the root of the file system? That's wrong you have to put an empty file **ssh** into the directory `/boot/`. Simply done with `sudo touch /boot/ssh`.

Comment: Could I just ask why you've set `eth0` and `wlan0` on different subnets? And are you certain you're routing traffic properly between the two subnets... that is to say, do you have other wifi devices on the `11` subnet that you can reach?

Comment: @Ingo Thanks for pointing that out.  I fixed that but didn't see any change.

Comment: @Seamus I didn't configure that myself.  Not sure why/how it got set to that. 
Would that be an issue created on the host machine or the Rpi?

Comment: No clue how that happened I'm afraid. All I can suggest is that you edit your question to point that out as it seems the others (@Ingo et al) have overlooked it, or perhaps recognized something I don't.